# Buffered/RingBuffer IO in Ruby + Amazon S3 non-blocking chunk reads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, delayed-job, nonblocking

I have huge csv files (100MB+) on amazon s3 and I want to read them in chunks and process them using ruby CSV library. I'm having a hard time creating the right IO object for csv processing:

```
buffer = TheRightIOClass.new
bytes_received = 0
RightAws::S3Interface.new(<access_key>, <access_secret>).retrieve_object(bucket, key) do     |chunk|
  bytes_received += buffer.write(chunk)
  if bytes_received >= 1*MEGABYTE
    bytes_received = 0
    csv(buffer).each do |row|
      process_csv_record(row)
    end
  end
end

def csv(io)
  @csv ||= CSV.new(io, headers: true)
end
```

I don't know what the right setup here should be and what the TheRightIOClass is. I don't want to load the entire file into memory with StringIO. Is there a bufferedio or ringbuffer in ruby to do this?
If anyone has a good solution using threads(no processes) and pipes I would love to see it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringIO and do some clever Error handling to insure you have an entire row in a chunk before handling it.  The packer class in this example just accumulates the parsed rows in memory until you flush them to disk or a database.

```
packer = Packer.new
object = AWS::S3.new.buckets[bucket].objects[path]
io = StringIO.new
csv = ::CSV.new(io, headers: true)
object.read do |chunk|
  #Append the most recent chunk and rewind the IO
  io << chunk
  io.rewind
  last_offset = 0
  begin
    while row = csv.shift do
      #Store the parsed row unless we're at the end of a chunk
      unless io.eof?
        last_offset = io.pos
        packer << row.to_hash
      end
    end
  rescue ArgumentError, ::CSV::MalformedCSVError => e
    #Only rescue malformed UTF-8 and CSV errors if we're at the end of chunk
    raise e unless io.eof?
  end
  #Seek to our last offset, create a new StringIO with that partial row & advance the cursor
  io.seek(last_offset)
  io.reopen(io.read)
  io.read
  #Flush our accumulated rows to disk every 1 Meg
  packer.flush if packer.bytes > 1*MEGABYTES 
end
#Read the last row
io.rewind
packer << csv.shift.to_hash
packer
```